# Perl sorting keys based on underlying keys

Tags: perl, hash

I am wondering if it is possible to sort the keys in a hash based on underlying keys?

To clarify, how would I sort and print the following alphabetically:

```
my %hash;
$hash{1}{b};
$hash{2}{c};
$hash{3}{a};
$hash{4}{d};
$hash{5}{e};
```

Comment: Is this a hash, or a hash of hash references?

Comment: You would need to know all the keys for all structures on the second level. What does the full structure look like?

Comment: It's a multidimensional hash, not sure if this answers your question but I'm a bit new to using hashes. I'm trying to use it to store layers of data in the way of $hash{ID}{type} and then easily list all the ID's sorted by type.

Comment: Maybe `$hash{ $id } = $type` makes more sense?

Comment: @Zyzyx you could use a hash slice combined with default sort (lexicographic sort): `@{ $hash{1} }{sort keys %{ $hash{1} }};`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's assume the data structure is a hash of hashes, where each sub-hash has exactly one key. In that case we can sort on the one key in the sub-hash alphabetically. The solution below does that by using the first one in the list of keys. This **does not make sense if there is more than one key** in that sub-hash because they are never ordered, and it would just be random.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (
    '2' => { 'c' => 1 },
    '4' => { 'd' => 1 },
    '3' => { 'a' => 1 },
    '5' => { 'e' => 1 },
    '1' => { 'b' => 1 },
);

my @sorted = sort { ( keys %{ $hash{$a} } )[0] cmp( keys %{ $hash{$b} } )[0] } 
    keys %hash;

foreach my $key (@sorted) {
    print Data::Dumper->Dump( [ $hash{$key} ], [$key] );
}
```

The code first creates a list of the keys of `%hash` sorted by the key inside of each of them, alphabetically. It then iterates that list of sorted keys and displays each key and value using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper).

Here's the output.

```
$3 = {
       'a' => 1
     };
$1 = {
       'b' => 1
     };
$2 = {
       'c' => 1
     };
$4 = {
       'd' => 1
     };
$5 = {
       'e' => 1
     };
```